# thrift 0.5 and 0.8 incompatible

Tags: thrift, scribe

I am using a java scribe client who depends on thrift-0.5.0.jar, but my appserver who depends the scribe client depends on libthrift-0.8.0.jar. When building the server, it reports incompatibility, Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:
1. Recompile the scribe-client's thrift file using thrift-0.8.0
2. Recompile the scribe-client with the new generated thrift classes
3. Recompile my app server with the newly compiled scribe-client